# Is it possible to use a string for NodeJS worker thread constructor?

Tags: node.js, node-worker-threads

In NodeJS documentation, the Worker constructor looks like it requires a path to a file that contains the code to execute on the new worker thread.

It's something like:

```
const encode_worker = new Worker(`./service-encode.js`, { workerData: config });
```

My question is if it's possible to pass in a string rather than a file for the Worker?  The reason I'm asking is due to how our main app is built and launched from its host application.

For example, is it possible to do

```
const encode_worker = new Worker(`console.log("Hello World")`, { workerData: config });
```

If so, how can we handle multiline strings for this?

Comment: As per [the constructor docs](https://nodejs.org/api/worker_threads.html#worker_threads_new_worker_filename_options): yes. You pass it a data-uri instead of a file path.

Comment: Thanks @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans can that be multiline text?

Comment: Given that base64 encoded data-uris are about as bog standard as it gets: sure? Compose your data, base64 encode it, and make sure to say [what the base mime type is](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme).

Answer (score 1):

The following worked for me.

```
const {
    Worker
} = require('worker_threads');

const workerString = `
const {
    parentPort
} = require('worker_threads');

parentPort.postMessage('hello')
`

const worker = new Worker(workerString, {eval: true});
worker.on('message', msg => {
    console.log(msg)
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on Niilo's answer, this is how I use the `{ eval: true }`  Worker mode:

```
const { Worker } = require('worker_threads');

const workerFn = () => {
    const { parentPort } = require('worker_threads');

    parentPort.postMessage('hello');
};

const worker = new Worker(workerFn.toString().substr(6), { eval: true });

worker.on('message', msg => {
    console.log(msg);
});
```

The idea is to use `Function.toString()` to get a more elegantly built worker code snippet, and have your worker code actually validated, transpiled and linted as normal JS would.

Beware that code in the `workerFn` arrow function above **cannot access any externally scoped variables from the main thread**, including having to `require` modules again within the worker thread.