# Cannot load data url in Worker Thread

Tags: node.js, worker-thread, node-worker-threads

My current worker thread which works fine with file path that tries to console log in that JS file:

```
console.log("hit here");
```

Now I get the base64 of that file and use Data URL to replace JS file path to get rid of additional file (https://nodejs.org/api/worker_threads.html#new-workerfilename-options):

```
const worker = new Worker("data:text/javascript;base64,Y29uc29sZS5sb2coImhpdCBoZXJlIik7Cg==", { workerData: {} });
```

But nothing happens.

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67912716/is-it-possible-to-use-a-string-for-nodejs-worker-thread-constructor